# Schindler's List Photo Filter C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how to make a Schindlers List (Movie) style photo filter for a .bmp file. For those who havent seen it, I want to be able to make everything grayscale except for red.

This is for a class and I am only allowed to use the following libraries : iostream, fstream, cstdlib, string, cstring.

The teacher was nice enough to give us the majority of the code, I just need to modify the pixels accordingly.

My grayscale algorithm isnt perfect. I got it by using fotor's grayscale filter and comparing the before and after RGB values.  When I run this function the entire image ends up grayscale even though the picture has colors in the range I declared.

If someone could help me make this work thatd be great!

```
void process( int& red, int& green, int& blue ) //schindler's list filter
{
    if( red   < 143 && red   > 80 &&
        green <  64 && green > 24 &&
        blue  <  70 && blue  >> 30 )//my red range
    {
        red = red;
        blue = blue;
        green = green;
    }
    else //if the pixel isnt red the program will go ahead and make it grayscale
    {
        red = ((red + green) / 2)*1.01;
        green =  red;
        blue = red;

    }
}
```

Comment: To format code, you need to prefix each code line with four spaces.

Comment: Your title is inventive but doesn't really describe the problem with your code.

Comment: Your entire `if` block does nothing!

Comment: @JBentley That's intentional. Just a bit wordy for my taste.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> blue >> 30
> ```

**Silly typo: you meant `blue > 30`.**

`blue >> 30` is basically always zero, which converts to `false` which leaves your "leave the colours as they are" block unreachable.

> If someone could help me make this work thatd be great!

We're not really here for that. Next time please do some debugging.

Remove conditions, output the values of expressions and variables, until you find the one that isn't what you expect. [Make a testcase](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/). Abstract away your specific use case (i.e. the name of a film is not relevant to the problem).

BTW, as a matter of style, `red = red` etc is utterly pointless!

Comment: Not, if you're paid by the semicolon!

Comment: Matter of fact, for blue between 0 and 255, this will always evaluate to false.

Comment: @Renan: Pretty sure that's what I just said.

Answer (score 1):

As a commentator said, in a classic RGB colorspace, a greyscale value is computed with the formula

```
grey = .2126*red + .7152*green + .0722*blue;
```

Also, if you just make a brutal transition between the colors you want to preserve and the grey areas, it might look like the colored zones have been painted over the picture.

I would rather apply a smoothing based on the color you want to make stand out.

```
// this is the center of the intervals you defined for your color
#define TARGET_R 111
#define TARGET_G  44
#define TARGET_B  50

// color distance to consider to mix grey and pure color
#define RADIUS 20 // R, G or B component

int dr = red   - TARGET_R;
int dg = green - TARGET_G;
int db = blue  - TARGET_B;
int dist = sqrt(dr*dr+dg*dg+db*db);   // distance from target color

int grey = .2126*red+.7152*green+.0722*blue; // grey color

float color; // fraction of pure color

if (dist > RADIUS)        // pure grey beyond radius
    color = 0;
else if (dist > RADIUS/2) // slope from 0 @ radius to 1 @ radius/2
    color = (RADIUS-dist)*2.0/RADIUS;
else                       // pure color between 0 and radius/2;
    color = 1;


grey *= (1-color); // grey part

red   = red   * color + grey;
green = green * color + grey;
blue  = blue  * color + grey;
```

Comment: As a matter of style, storing distance^2 in a variable called "dist" is likely to trip up somebody reading the code quickly.  Really, going out of your way to avoid a square root may not even matter appreciably these days.  And there's lots of ways to create a luminance version of a color image.  My personal favorite is usually just to take the green channel and use that.  Tends to look nice, IMO.

Comment: Your formula to calculate the grayscale value doesn't preserve the luminance. See [Grayscale - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) for more information.

Comment: @wrosecrans You're right, avoiding float operations is just a bad habit leftover from the 90's :) As for greyscale, well, it all depends on the kind of picture. The basic RGB average is a jack of all trades. Taking only green as a base for a picture of seawaves would probably look a bit strange, don't you think ?

Comment: @IInspectable You're right. It's a bad approximation, but the exact translation would have been a bit too much for a quick bit of code off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could take is to convert the RGB color to HSV (Hue Saturation Value) color space, and than bring the saturation down only if the hue is not in a specific range. For example:

```
if( 30 < h && h < 330 ) s = 0
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV